How to change the port for NiFi in eclipse che
I am trying to run Apache NiFi in my che workspace and running into issues. I added the below to my devfile:
  - name: dev-nifi
    container:
      image: apache/nifi
      memoryLimit: 2Gi
      cpuRequest: "0.5"
      mountSources: true
      endpoints:
        - name: dev-nifi
          protocol: https
          secure: true
          targetPort: 8443

When I try to start my workspace, I see the below error:
Error creating DevWorkspace deployment: Container dev-nifi has state CrashLoopBackOff

My doubt is that it is having a port conflict with the kubernetes control that is running on the same port. I want to know if I can force NiFi to use a separate port.
Appreciate all the help.
Thanks
